# Make Git Bisect do a force checkout or otherwise overwrite local changes

Tags: git, git-bisect

I'm git bisecting a Unity3D repository and every time I open the Unity3D editor to check if the current revision is good or bad, Unity3D dirties a few files, forcing me to do a hard reset before continuing with the bisection.

This is because if I don't reset, I'll get:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        Platform/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
        Platform/ProjectSettings/ProjectSettings.asset
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Is there any way to tell git bisect to use `--force` in its checkout call or otherwise avoid having to reset every single time?

Comment: I guess as workaround you could set a custom command alias (if on linux/unix) like e.g. `alias gitbi='git reset --hard; git bisect`, then you could use `gitbi bad` and `gitbi good` to tag the revisions (while automatically cleaning the repo before-hand so that the autom. checkout can succeed).

Comment: @Jay That's not a bad idea. And one that simply didn't occur to me. If I don't get any better answers feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this for `git bisect run`? It is quite annoying that this prevents automated running of `git bisect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the source code, there is not a built-in way to do this.

I've [submitted a patch](https://lore.kernel.org/git/pull.1641.git.git.1705302307639.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/T/) ([github](https://github.com/git/git/pull/1641)) that adds this feature, hopefully it makes it into a release.